# Handmade Estimator modifies parameters in __init__?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I am preparing a tailored preprocessing phase which is suppose to become part of a `sklearn.pipeline.Pipeline`. Here's the code of the preprocessor:

```
import string
from nltk import wordpunct_tokenize
from nltk.stem.snowball import SnowballStemmer
from nltk import sent_tokenize
from sklearn.base import BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin
from . import stopwords

class NLTKPreprocessor(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, stopwords=stopwords.STOPWORDS_DE,
                 punct=string.punctuation,
                 lower=True, strip=True, lang='german'):
        """
        Based on:
        https://bbengfort.github.io/tutorials/2016/05/19/text-classification-nltk-sckit-learn.html
        """

        self.lower = lower
        self.strip = strip
        self.stopwords = set(stopwords)
        self.punct = set(punct)
        self.stemmer = SnowballStemmer(lang)
        self.lang = lang

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        return self

    def inverse_transform(self, X):
        return [" ".join(doc) for doc in X]

    def transform(self, X):
        return [
            list(self.tokenize(doc)) for doc in X
        ]

    def tokenize(self, document):
        # Break the document into sentences
        for sent in sent_tokenize(document, self.lang):
            for token in wordpunct_tokenize(sent):
                # Apply preprocessing to the token
                token = token.lower() if self.lower else token
                token = token.strip() if self.strip else token
                token = token.strip('_') if self.strip else token
                token = token.strip('*') if self.strip else token

                # If stopword, ignore token and continue
                if token in self.stopwords:
                    continue

                # If punctuation, ignore token and continue
                if all(char in self.punct for char in token):
                    continue

                # Lemmatize the token and yield
                # lemma = self.lemmatize(token, tag)
                stem = self.stemmer.stem(token)
                yield stem
```

Next, here is the pipeline I construct:

```
pipeline = Pipeline(
    [
        ('preprocess', nltkPreprocessor),
        ('vectorize', TfidfVectorizer(tokenizer=identity, preprocessor=None, lowercase=False)),
        ('clf', SGDClassifier(max_iter=1000, tol=1e-3))       
    ]
)
```

This all works nicely for a single pass; for example `pipeline.fit(X,y)` works nicely. However, when putting this pipeline inside a grid search

```
parameters = {
    'vectorize__use_idf': (True, False),
    'vectorize__max_df': np.arange(0.8, 1.01 ,0.05),
    'vectorize__smooth_idf': (True, False),
    'vectorize__sublinear_tf': (True, False),
    'vectorize__norm': ('l1', 'l2'),
    'clf__loss':  ('hinge', 'log', 'modified_huber', 'squared_hinge', 'perceptron'),
    'clf__alpha': (0.00001, 0.000001),
    'clf__penalty': ('l1', 'l2', 'elasticnet')
}
grid_search = GridSearchCV(pipeline, parameters, n_jobs=-1, verbose=1)
grid_search.fit(X_train, y_train)
```

I get the following warning:

```
/Users/user/anaconda3/envs/myenv/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sklearn/base.py:115: DeprecationWarning: Estimator NLTKPreprocessor modifies parameters in __init__. This behavior is deprecated as of 0.18 and support for this behavior will be removed in 0.20.
  % type(estimator).__name__, DeprecationWarning)
```

I don't understand what should be changed/fixed in the implementation. How can I maintain the functionality and remove the warning?

Answer (score 3):

Check out the developer guide of sklearn, [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#estimators) and the [following paragraph](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#rolling-your-own-estimator). I would try to cohere as much to it as possible to make sure such messages are avoided (even if you never intend to contribute it).

They prescribe that estimators should have *no logic* in the __init__ function! This most likely causes your error.

I put my validation or transformation of init parameters (as prescribed also in the description) at the beginning of the fit() method, which has to be called in any case.

Also, note [this](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.utils.estimator_checks.check_estimator.html#sklearn.utils.estimator_checks.check_estimator) utility which you can use to test your estimator if it confirms to the scikit learn API.

## Edit (as response to your comment, but with code formatting):

Well, not logic. To quote from the links:
"To summarize, an __init__ should look like:

```
def __init__(self, param1=1, param2=2):
    self.param1 = param1
    self.param2 = param2
```

There should be no logic, not even input validation, and the parameters should not be changed." [1](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/contributing.html#estimators)

So I guess as @uberwach detailed the set construction and creation of SnowballStemmer instance probably violates the "should not be changed"part.

## Edit 2:

As addition to the below comment. This would be one general way of doing it (another specific as mentioned by @uberwach later in your tokenize method):

```
class NLTKPreprocessor(BaseEstimator, TransformerMixin):
    def __init__(self, stopwords=stopwords.STOPWORDS_DE,
                 punct=string.punctuation,
                 lower=True, strip=True, lang='german'):
        self.lower = lower
        self.strip = strip
        self.stopwords = stopwords
        self.punct = punct
        self.lang = lang

    def fit(self, X, y=None):
        self.stopword_set = set(self.stopwords)
        self.punct_set = set(self.punct)
        self.stemmer = SnowballStemmer(self.lang)
        return self
```

Comment: Do you note any logic in my `__init__.py`?

Comment: So how do I initialize with a `tuple` for example and then cast it to a set (for better lookups)?

Comment: For my transformers and estimators I do all transformations or creation of new derived attributes in the fit() method. It can always later be tested if fit was called. GridSearch should for TransformerMixIn always call fit first anyhow. When I transform data anywhere in the code I use the helper method fit_transform() which is automatically available as you inherit from TransformerMixin.

Comment: My strategy is very similar to Marcus and I never had problems (anecdotal evidence, I know...). But the design makes sense in that way.

Answer (score 1):

I read the code under https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/master/sklearn/base.py

Could reproduce the warning message. They went away after two changes:

1. `frozenset` rather than `set`. As a `set` considered mutable and as such will turn out to be different after a copy.
2. Initializing `self.stemmer` in the `tokenize` method rather than in `__init__`.